# Parse only date part not time logstash

Tags: logstash

My log pattern is something like this

```
other|vandana|test|20160804100203
```

last one is date `2016 08 04 10 02 03` I have created a field which have the last value `field = 20160804100203` now I want a new field which only have the date part not the time means it should be `fieldnew = 20160804` I tried this but it doesn't work

```
date{
match => ['field','MMM dd YYY']
}
```

Comment: you can use regex for that

Comment: I have tried mutate {  } and add_field inside it but it is taking regex as string can you write code for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ruby` filter:

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => "event['fieldnew'] = event['field'][0..7]"
  }
}
```